# prewhitening (whitening transform) in terms of expected-value-wr-sigma-algebra

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

I'm trying to understand the mathematics of prewhitening a little better. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitening_transformation, e.g.)

Taking the conditional expectation of an RV with respect to a $\sigma$-algebra is a projection, and an orthogonal projection if we restrict to square-integrable RVs. It seems like the whitening transform is a form of the Gram-Schmidt algorithm where, at any step of the algorithm, the projection is conditional expectation with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the RVs already processed.

Perhaps I am completely out to lunch, though, because it seems like the process outlined above would not lead to a scalar matrix (like with whitening) but just a diagonal matrix. Does anyone know of an interpretation of whitening in these terms?

Comment: The whitening transformation described in the Wikipedia article that you linked to assumes that you have a random vector with a known covariance structure.  By "the projection is conditional expectation with respect to the $\sigma$ algebra generated by the RV's already processed" it would seem that you're referring to some kind of process in which $\Sigma$ is dynamically updated.  Could you be more specific about what you're referring to here?

Comment: By ``processed'', I just meant taken into account by previous steps of the Gram-Schmidt algorithm/process. 

More symbolically, I was thinking of doing something like this: let $\Sigma_j = \sigma(X_1,\dots,X_j)$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the first $j$ random variables of the $n$ RVs you are working with. 

Begin G-S by letting $Y_1 = X_1$.

Next, for $j=2,\dots,n$, let $Y_j = X_j - \mathbb{E}[X_j | \Sigma_{j-1}]$.

End with random vector $(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)$.